# Have two instances of a Chrome Cast App connect to the same session

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast

I'm trying to reproduce some of the features found in the Tic-Tac-Toe sample, but instead using the Chrome Cast API. Does anyone know how to connect multiple devices running Chrome and the Cast extension to a single Cast session?

The only documented (somewhat) way of connecting is using the `api.launch` method, and when that is called from the second device it re-opens the receiver page which reloads all the content (disconnecting the first device).

I've also tried creating a new connection by POST-ing to http://:8008/connection/, which gives me back a WebSocket URL. When I try to connect a WebSocket to that ws:// URL, I get a "Unexpected response code: 408" and am unable to connect.

Comment: Ah, maybe I'm missing something obvious. I will investigate later, but my thought is that the webapp should send the activityId from the client to the server. When a new client arrives on the page, they will scan the network for receivers. When they see a receiver, they will ask the webapp server if there are any existing activities for that receiver. If so, perhaps it can just start passing the Cast API the activityId retrieved from the webapp server.

Comment: No, that does not work. I tried to use the same activityId in another browser and got an error "Activity does not exist".

Comment: Currently running into the same issue, have you found a solution for this problem yet?

Comment: Note: I've added an issue to the bug tracker about this: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=75

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the the [AutoJoinPolicy](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy) at [chrome.cast.ApiConfig](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.ApiConfig). If you set this value to `chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.ORIGIN_SCOPED` it will work over different windows (not sure how it will work with different chrome instances).

For example:

```
apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(
  sessionRequest,
  this.sessionListener.bind(this),
  this.receiverListener.bind(this),
  chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.ORIGIN_SCOPED
);
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i haven't gone back to my chromecast now for a while but if i dig it out i will give it a try